# What is the correct term for a non-generator in Python?

Tags: python, iterator

An iterator is the top category, and a generator is a particular kind of iterator.

What is the correct term for things like a usual list that are iterators but not generators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists are *iterables*. You can produce an iterator for them by calling `iter(iterable)`.

There is no special term that includes iterators and excludes generators.

See the [Python glossary](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) for precise definitions, for [*iterator*](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator), [*iterable*](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) and [*generator*](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator).

For example, the *generator* entry includes:

> A function which returns an iterator.

It is quite common to use a generator function to implement the iterator for an iterable, by implementing [`object.__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__):

```
class SomeContainer(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for elem in self._datastructure:
            if elem.visible:
                yield elem.value
```

So `SomeContainer` instances are *iterable* (just like lists are), `iter(iterable)` produces an *iterator*, which *just happens to be a generator object*.

Comment: Would a generator object also be an iterable then, because it has an `__iter__` function and yields an iterable? Or do I get this wrong?

Comment: @Xiphias: every iterator is iterable, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Lists are not Iterators. Lists are *Iterables*, and when you call `iter(somelist)` it produces an Iterator. What kind of Iterator is produced depends on the Iterable in question, the one for a list is quite adequately named listiterator.

Any generator is an Iterator.
Any Iterator is an Iterable (try `iter(iter(somelist))`.
Not any Iterable (a list, for example) is an Iterator, but any Iterable returns an Iterator when you call `iter(someiterable)` or `someiterable.__iter__()`.

edit: Here's a short (Python 3) example:

```
>>> import collections
>>> import random
>>> 
>>> class MyIterable:
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return MyIterator()
>>>
>>> class MyIterator:
...     def __next__(self):
...         return random.randint(-10, 10)
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return self
... 
>>> mable = MyIterable()
>>> mitor = iter(mable)
>>> isinstance(mable, collections.Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance(mable, collections.Iterator)
False
>>> isinstance(mitor, collections.Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance(mitor, collections.Iterator)
True
>>> next(mitor)
-7
>>> next(mitor)
-3
>>> next(mitor)
-3
>>> next(mitor)
7
>>> next(mable)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'MyIterable' object is not an iterator
```

Comment: I see. Not any iterable is an iterator because generators are iterable but not iterators?

Comment: @Xiphias not quite. A generator is a special kind of Iterator, so any generator is an Iterator. Not any Iterable is an Iterator because Iterables and Iterators are two different things. Iterables are able to produce Iterators. Iterators are objects with an `__iter__` and a `__next__` method. All Iterators are Iterables, because they can produce Iterators (by convention, they just return themself when `iter` is called on an Iterator).